# The Addition of the letter 'he' in Yonatan's name

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of, spelling-variants

I've been trying to understand the significance to to addition of the letter 'he' in the name of Yonatan in 1 Shmuel 19:1 making it Yehonatan. Is there any connection here with the name change Avram to Avraham? Are there any recommended sources to learn more?

([related question about an extra 'he' in Yosef's name](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73577/759))

Comment: Im guessing it's to imply G-d is with them?

Comment: Good question, it may be that the spirit of G-d was with them